# Python subprocess error management. Not able to catch non-zero exit status

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, subprocess

I'm using the subprocess module in python to connect my 3G dongle to the 3G network using sakis3g.

See here my code used:

```
check_output(['sakis3g', '--sudo', 'connect', 'OTHER="USBMODEM"', 'USBMODEM="12d1:1001"', 'APN="internet"'])
```

On occasion my dongle may poop out and give an error in the nature of: *"This device does not have any GSM capabilities..."*

Which I can completely live with since all it needs is a simple retry and it will usually work just fine.

However using subprocesses I run into the error `returned non-zero exit status` and it will crash my software completely.

Since all I need is a retry, I tried to code in a `try: ... except: ...`.
The error I am trying to catch is `subprocess.CalledProcessError` which should be returned by `check_output` in case of a non-zero exit status according to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

However, that did not seem to fix the problem, the issue still persists:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 91, in <module>
    print connect_3G()
  File "run.py", line 28, in connect_3G
    check_call(['sakis3g', '--sudo', 'connect', 'OTHER="USBMODEM"', 'USBMODEM="12d1:1001"', 'APN="internet"'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['sakis3g', '--sudo', 'connect', 'OTHER="USBMODEM"', 'USBMODEM="12d1:1001"', 'APN="internet"']' returned non-zero exit status 95
```

So I tried to catch the exception in the broadest way possible, by simply using `except:` and even when done this, the error still comes through and crashes the software.

I am at a loss trying to catch this error properly, would anyone be able to tell me what exactly is happening here, because it seems like it's rather difficult to catch errors caused by subprocesses at this point (for me).

See the complete function I intended on using here:

```
def connect_3G():
    while True:
        check_output(['sakis3g', '--sudo', 'connect', 'OTHER="USBMODEM"', 'USBMODEM="12d1:1001"', 'APN="internet"'])
        try:
            return 'Connected to ip: {}'.format(json.loads(requests.get('http://httpbin.org/ip').content)['origin'])
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            print 'Oops, problem connecting to 3G. Better retry fam.'
```

Comment: Looks like the exception is thrown by the `check_output` call which is not inside the try except block?

Comment: @strubbly Yep that seemed to be the issue, can't believe I overlooked that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're doing the right thing...but move the code that's throwing the exception inside the `try` block!

```
def connect_3G():
    while True:
        try:
            check_output(['sakis3g', '--sudo', 'connect', 'OTHER="USBMODEM"', 'USBMODEM="12d1:1001"', 'APN="internet"'])
            return 'Connected to ip: {}'.format(json.loads(requests.get('http://httpbin.org/ip').content)['origin'])
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            print 'Oops, problem connecting to 3G. Better retry fam.'
```

Comment: Welp I can't believe I did not see that.

Answer (score 2):

Besides, just print out the error, may help you debug the code:

```
def connect_3G():
    while True:
        try:
            check_output(['sakis3g', '--sudo', 'connect', 'OTHER="USBMODEM"', 'USBMODEM="12d1:1001"', 'APN="internet"'])
            return 'Connected to ip: {}'.format(json.loads(requests.get('http://httpbin.org/ip').content)['origin'])
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as error:
            print 'Oops, problem connecting to 3G. Better retry fam.', error.message
```

Comment: Good thinking but the root of this error is known to me and is not something I can solve unfortunately.